For all natural $n$ find $\operatorname{lcm}(n^5 + 4n, 10)$
I need to find lcm of $n^5 + 4n$ and 10 $\ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$.
What have i done so far:
$$n^5 + 4n = n^5 - n + 5n$$
and, by Fermat's little theorem
$$n^5 - n \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 5) \implies (n^5 - n + 5n) \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 5)$$
Also, $\forall \ n \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 2) \ [n^5 + 4n, 10] = n^5 + 4n$.
How can i describe $[n^5 + 4n, 10]$ for odd n?

Hint: Use that $\gcd(m, n)\cdot lcm(m, n)=mn$. Then show that $\gcd(n^5+4n,10)=5$ for $n$ odd, and  $\gcd(n^5+4n,10)=10$ for $n$ even.

Isn 't $\gcd(40,2)=2$?

Is this not sufficient as a comment?

@Sahaj  There should be field for hints. I often had a complaint not to give partial answers in a comment, so I decided for the answer field.

@DietrichBurde I even had one of my hint comments deleted by a mod, which led to a math meta article that upvoted the mod's answer, and resulted in +8/-8 to my posted question.

@user2661923 nothing personal but was that mod XanderHanderson?

Yes, $ gcd(n^5 + 4n, 10) = 5 \cdot gcd(\frac{n^5 + 4n}{5}, 2)$, and $gcd(\frac{n^5 + 4n}{5}, 2)$ is either 1 or 2.

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Yes. See this math meta posting.

We know that:
$$n^{5} + 4n \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$
Proof:
$$n \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \implies 4n \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \land n^{5} \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$
$$n \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \implies 4n \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \land n^{5} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
$$n \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \implies 4n \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \land n^{5} \equiv 2 \pmod 5$$
$$n \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \implies 4n \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \land n^{5} \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$
$$n \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \implies 4n \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \land n^{5} \equiv 4 \pmod 5$$
We also know that:
$$n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies n^{5} + 4n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$
Proof:
$$n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies n^{5} \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$
$$n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies 4n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$
Then:
$$n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies lcm(n^{5}+4n, 10) = 2n^{5} + 8n$$
